# Custom FIX Tag for Verifix

Tags: fix-protocol

I'm trying to simulate an 8 (Execution Report) message from a particular firm who uses a custom FIX tag (not standard in the Execution Report Template).

Is there any way to add this **custom tag** to my fill messages?

***I'm using Verifix 6.1 to send FIX 4.4 messages***

I tried updating the XML file by hand and the custom values were deleted:
[image: Verifix Custom Tag]

The XML I added:
    
  `<metaData position="1" tag="22036" protocolVersion="FIX.4.4">
      <textFieldComponent tag="22036" text="xxxx" overridable="false"/>
  </metaData>
  <metaData position="1" tag="1430" protocolVersion="FIX.4.4">
       <textFieldComponent tag="1430" text="x" overridable="false"/>
  </metaData>`

Comment: Your question is incomplete without telling us about your FIX engine or simulator.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier sorry, it was late on a Friday afternoon when I posted. Please see update.

Comment: Sorry, don't know Verifix, but I'm sure they support this, since *every* counterparty screws with the DataDictionary to some degree.  I'd be very surprised if this wasn't in their docs somewhere.  Try searching for "custom tags" (or "custom" anything, really).

Comment: If I remember correctly Verifix used Quickfix engine under the hood, when I used it 5 years ago. And if I am recollecting properly there is an XML file which specifies the message constructs for Verifix.

Comment: @DumbCoder Thanks, That was a good idea but Verifix didn't like me trying to edit behind its back. The XML is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add custom fields to messages in VeriFix use the Field Definitions menu to create the custom field and then the Message Definitions menu to add the field to the message as follows.

1) Field Definitions > Create New > Enter details of custom field > Save

2) Message Definitions > Open message type you want to add the new field to > Add Field > Select newly created field from list to add it to the message > Save